# Transforming claims with Windows Azure Active Directory (WAAD)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, azure, claims

I am currently using windows azure active directory as a single sign-on in my MVC.NET application and that portion works great. I can authenticate against WAAD and get my ClaimsPrinicipal loaded without any problems.

The next step was to transform the claims retrieved from WAAD by adding new claims from a different data source. To this extent I created a class inheriting the ClaimsAuthenticationManager (below). The claims get added to the Principal and get persisted to the session cookie in the CreateSession method.

My problem right now is that ClaimsPrincipal.Current does not carry any of the additional claims that I've added. When I set a breakpoint in the SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived event, I can see that there's a discrepancy between the ClaimsPrincipal.Current

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Email)
Count = 0
```

and e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal.

```
e.SessionToken.ClaimsPrincipal.FindAll(ClaimTypes.Email)
Count = 1
[0]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress: me@mydomain.com}
```

What am I missing here? In all the samples that dealt with transforming claims that I could find there's no mention of manually reloading the ClaimsPrinicipal from the cookie. Would the session security token event be the right place to reload the ClaimsPrincipal or am I breaking the security model?

Thanks.

```
public class MyAuthenticationManager : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
        }

        var transformedPrincipal = this.CreateUserPrincipal(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        this.CreateSession(transformedPrincipal);

        return transformedPrincipal;
    }

    private ClaimsPrincipal CreateUserPrincipal(String userName)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
        var user = SecurityController.GetUserIdentity(userName);

        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName));

        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyCustom"));
    }

    private void CreateSession(ClaimsPrincipal transformedPrincipal)
    {
        var sessionSecurityToken = new SessionSecurityToken(transformedPrincipal, TimeSpan.FromHours(8));

        if (FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule != null &&
        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.ContainsSessionTokenCookie(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies))
        {
            return;
        }
        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionSecurityToken);
        //Added line below as per suggestion in one of the posts
        //Doesn't seem to have any effect
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = transformedPrincipal;
        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.SessionSecurityTokenReceived += SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived;
    }

    void SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived(object sender, SessionSecurityTokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("SessionAuthenticationModule_SessionSecurityTokenReceived");
    }
```

Comment: Is the MyAuthenticationManager configured in the application's .config file?

Comment: Your test is flawed, as you are attempting to find claims with the string "Email", it should be either ClaimTypes.Email or "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"

Comment: Yes the MyAuthenticationManager is configured in the .config file. The Authenticate method is called, I can step through it.

Comment: Yes the test was flawed, I updated it to ClaimTypes.Email but it's still the same behavior. I picked email, but I have other custom claims that I was testing with, so nothing changed from that perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I had to access the claims through ClaimsIdentity instead of ClaimsPrincipal. Now I can successfully access the claims from any view or controller in my application.

```
((ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity).FindAll(ClaimTypes.Email)
Count = 1
    [0]: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress: me@mydomain.com}
```

Final codebase in AuthenticationManager looks like this (note that there is no explicit assignment operation to the ClaimsPrincipal on the current thread).

```
public class MyAuthenticationManager : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {
        if (!incomingPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return base.Authenticate(resourceName, incomingPrincipal);
        }

        var transformedPrincipal = this.CreateUserPrincipal(incomingPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        this.CreateSession(transformedPrincipal);

        return transformedPrincipal;
    }

    private ClaimsPrincipal CreateUserPrincipal(String userName)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
        var user = SecurityController.GetUserIdentity(userName);

        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
        claims.Add(new Claim("UserId", user.Id.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, user.FirstName));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Surname, user.LastName));
        //claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userName));

        if (user.Account != null)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("AccountId", user.Account.Id.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim("AccountName", user.Account.Name.ToString()));
        }
        if (user.Owner != null)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("OwnerId", user.Owner.Id.ToString()));
            claims.Add(new Claim("OwnerName", user.Owner.Name.ToString()));
        }

        return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "MyCustom"));
    }

    private void CreateSession(ClaimsPrincipal transformedPrincipal)
    {
        if (FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule != null &&
        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.ContainsSessionTokenCookie(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies))
        {
            return;
        }
        var sessionSecurityToken = new SessionSecurityToken(transformedPrincipal, TimeSpan.FromHours(8));
        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionSecurityToken);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you adding your ClaimsPrincipal (after the transformation) back to Thread.CurrentPrincipal. Please try

```
private void CreateSession(ClaimsPrincipal transformedPrincipal)
    {
        var sessionSecurityToken = new SessionSecurityToken(transformedPrincipal, TimeSpan.FromHours(8));

        if (FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule != null &&
        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.ContainsSessionTokenCookie(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies))
        {
            return;
        }
        FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(sessionSecurityToken);
        //Following is the missing line of code.
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = transformedPrincipal;
   }
```

Comment: I assigned the principal to the CurrentPrincipal but that had no effect. I'm going to try to build a separate POC solution following the articles again.

Comment: are you sure cookies are written and code is not returning from the following code FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule.ContainsSessionTokenCookie(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies))
        {
            return;
        }

Comment: Also can you try writing cookie with following SessionAuthenticationModule sam = FederatedAuthentication.SessionAuthenticationModule;
var st= sam.CreateSessionSecurityToken(transformedPrincipal, null, validFrom, validTo, isPersistantCookie);sam.WriteSessionTokenToCookie(st);

Comment: Yes, the cookie is being written. I've set breakpoint in the "return" portion and it never gets hit. Also I can see the cookie via the developer's tools in chrome.

I tried changing the code to write the cookie as per your suggestion and that didn't affect anything.